# ng-if doesn't work with getDay()

Tags: html, css, angularjs, date

This is my code:

```
  <h2>HEUTE</h2>
  <h2 ng-if="d == 1">Montag: {{cat.montag}}</h2>
  <h2 ng-if="d == 2">Dienstag: {{cat.dienstag}}</h2>
  <h2 ng-if="d == 3">Mittwoch: {{cat.mittwoch}}</h2>
  <h2 ng-if="d == 4">Donnerstag: {{cat.donnerstag}}</h2>
  <h2 ng-if="d == 5">Freitag: {{cat.freitag}}</h2>
  <h2 ng-if="d == 6">Samstag: {{cat.samstag}}</h2>
  <h2 ng-if="d == 0">Sonntag: {{cat.sonntag}}</h2>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.getDate = function() {
      var n = new Date();
      $scope.d = n.getDay();
    }
```

The problem is that when I insert the second ng-if (Dienstag) the correct day isn't shown anymore. Do i missed something?

Comment: The second ng-if ? Where is the second ng-if ? What is the value of `d` ?

Comment: It's working for me, did you not forget to call getDate somewhere ? can you add some code that goes along with it ? That sole piece of code is wokring.

Comment: You just forgot to call the function `getDay()`

Comment: Yeah.. that was it  Thank you @Weedoze

Comment: @olivier As a suggestion to make you code better you could use [**`ngSwitch`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this function that you've defined here:

```
myApp.controller("myController", ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getDate = function() {
      var n = new Date();
      $scope.d = n.getDay();
    }
]);
```

It is just assigning value to a `$scope` variable `d`. If that's all you want to do then why not do it directly by declaring these variables? Like this

```
myApp.controller("myController", ['$scope', '$http',
   function($scope, $http) {
      var n = new Date();
      $scope.d = n.getDay();
   }
]);
```

---

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myController">

  <h2>HEUTE</h2>
  <h2 ng-if="d == 1">Montag: {{cat.montag}}</h2>
  <h2 ng-if="d == 2">Dienstag: {{cat.dienstag}}</h2>
  <h2 ng-if="d == 3">Mittwoch: {{cat.mittwoch}}</h2>
  <h2 ng-if="d == 4">Donnerstag: {{cat.donnerstag}}</h2>
  <h2 ng-if="d == 5">Freitag: {{cat.freitag}}</h2>
  <h2 ng-if="d == 6">Samstag: {{cat.samstag}}</h2>
  <h2 ng-if="d == 0">Sonntag: {{cat.sonntag}}</h2>

  <script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller("myController", ['$scope', '$http',
      function($scope, $http) {
        var n = new Date();
        $scope.d = n.getDay();
      }
    ]);
  </script>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 2):

its working ..

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
     var n = new Date();
   console.log(n.getDay());
      $scope.d =  n.getDay();
});
```

```html
 <script data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.4.x"></script>
   
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h2>HEUTE</h2>
  <h2 ng-if="d == 1">Montag: {{cat.montag}}</h2>
  <h2 ng-if="d == 2">Dienstag: {{cat.dienstag}}</h2>
  <h2 ng-if="d == 3">Mittwoch: {{cat.mittwoch}}</h2>
  <h2 ng-if="d == 4">Donnerstag: {{cat.donnerstag}}</h2>
  <h2 ng-if="d == 5">Freitag: {{cat.freitag}}</h2>
  <h2 ng-if="d == 6">Samstag: {{cat.samstag}}</h2>
  <h2 ng-if="d == 0">Sonntag: {{cat.sonntag}}</h2>
  </body>
```